# Как запустить другое приложение на golang?

Tags: golang

Есть 2 приложения.
Как просто запустить file2.exe из file1.exe ?

Answer (score 3):

тебе поможет пакет "os/exec"

Run запускает комманду и ждет ее окончания

Start запускает и не ждет, пока не вызовешь Wait

[пример](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("some input")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("in all caps: %q\n", out.String())
}
```